# Is there any definition for homogeneous rotations?

Tags: matrices, definition, projective-space, homogeneous-spaces

Most of the geometric transformations can only be represented into square matrices via homogeneous coordinates, e.g., translation and 3D rotations with axes not through coordindate system origin.

Since homogeneous coordinates means algebraic representation in `projective space` where the concept `distance` becomes invalid and undefined, I am not sure whether there is any algebraic definition to homogeneous matrices of rotations in any textbook or literature?

So that I can identify the following homogeneous matrix as a rotation or not per such a definition:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 50+10 \sqrt{3} & 15 \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{35}-30 & 5 \sqrt{3}+3 \sqrt{35}-10 & 40-20 \sqrt{3}+4 \sqrt{35} \\
 15 \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{35}-30 & 18+26 \sqrt{3} & 6-3 \sqrt{3}+5 \sqrt{35} & 88-44 \sqrt{3}+4 \sqrt{35} \\
5 \sqrt{3}-3 \sqrt{35} -10 & 6-3 \sqrt{3}-5 \sqrt{35} & 2+34 \sqrt{3} & 32 \sqrt{3}+8 \sqrt{35}-64 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 70 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such transform which don't actually *project*, i.e. which have the form $$
  T = \begin{pmatrix}
    L_T & c_T \\
    0\,0 & t_T
  \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{where } L_T \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3},\, c_T \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 1},\, t \neq 0
$$
you can simply check if $L_T$ is the matrix of a *linear* rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To verify that $L_T$ is indeed a rotation matrix, and find the angle and axis, you can use (one or more) of the following facts

1. $L_T$ is a rotation exactly if $\det L_T = 1$ and $L_T^* = L_T^{-1}$ (where $^*$ means *tranposed*, i.e. the transposed of $L_T$ is the inverse of $L_T$).
2. If $L_T$ is a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by angle $\varphi$ around the axis $a$, it has a real eigenvalue $1$ and complex eigenvalues $e^{i\phi},e^{-i\phi}$. The axis $a$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the real eigenvalue $1$, i.e. you can find it by solving $(L_T - I)x = 0$.
3. If $L_T$ is a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by angle $\varphi$, the *trace* (i.e. the sum of diagonal elements) of $L_T$ is $1 + 2\cos \varphi$.

Note that *axis* in the above refers to the axis of $L_T$, not the axis of $T$. To find the axis of $T$, you can e.g. find two independent solutions $x_1,x_2$ of $$
  Tx = x \text{,}
$$
i.e. two eigenvalues of $T$ with $x_1 \neq \lambda x_2$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How to determine the rotation axis and rotation angle this way?

Comment: You can also extract the axis by evaluating $A=L_T-L_T^\ast$ (an antisymmetric matrix) and reading out $a_x=A_{yz}$, $a_y=A_{zx}=-A_{xz}$ and $a_z=A_{xy}$, and normalizing it. The overall sign depends on handedness of your coordinate frame. This method is computationally much less demanding - instead of finding an eigenvector (a relatively expensive operation), you just need three subtractions.

Comment: This method determines rotation axis direction easier; How to determine the rotation axis, which needs both a direction and a fixed point ( coordinate system origin does not work for this case  )?

Comment: @fgp  is there any algebraic definition of general rotations available this way?

Comment: @LCFactorization What do you mean? My answer gives you several ways to define affine rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ via properties of their transformation matrices.

Comment: From the title of this question, I am actually asking whether there is any `algebraic definition` to a general rotation in 3D projective space where `distance` is invalid; how do you obtain such properties? There should be a theoretically rigorous definition, I believe, which does not depend on the Euclidean intuitions...

Comment: It seems this is acceptable

Answer (score 1):

I notice in this article [A General Homogeneous Matrix Formulation to 3D Rotation Geometric Transformations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6055) there is a new definition on 3D rotations in exactly homogeneous matrices.

The definition is based on reflections, i.e., a rotation is the composition transformation of two reflection. This is actually a definition in the classical approach. However, the only difference might be, the reflection was defined in a completely different way by the authors in their own cited articles.

Hope this helps.